# Non trivial colouring of the edges of an infinite complete graph

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Can you build a probabilistic scheme for colouring each edge (independently of all other edges) of the complete graph G on the positive integers such that the probability that G contains an infinite monochromatic complete subgraph is neither 0 nor 1?

Comment: The question has been answered, but I'm still confused. Isn't Ramsey's theorem exactly the statement that there is always a infinite monochromatic complete subgraph, so that the probability would be identically 1?

Comment: Well the infinite Ramsey theorem holds if you use only finitely many colours, but there is no such assumption here. Does that help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like this would go against the [Kolmogorov 0-1 law.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero-one_law).  If we let X<sub>i</sub> denote the  coloring of all of the edges from i to integers larger than i, wouldn't the existence of an infinite monochromatic subgraph be a tail event?

Comment: I didn't know the definition of a tail event, nor did I know Kolmogorow's 0-1 law. But yeah, it's seems you are right... Disappointing.